# vnc take screen print of machine

Tags: go, vnc, vnc-server

i looking to take screen print of vnc machine with golang, 
my actual function is :

.....

code working, problem is when function connect to vnc server  not wait to load vnc image and image black:

[image]

.. take print first to finish loading. my neeed is take print screen only after complete loaded.

example code :

```
VncPrint("1.176.68.198","123456")
```

how i can fix this problem ?